# Array representation of a min-heap

Tags: algorithm

If an array is has a size of 20 (0-19) and the mapping is from (i-1)/2 to a parent. What does mapping of (i-1)/2 mean in relation to representing a min-heap of a size of 13?

Comment: The mapping is the same regardless of the size of the array.

Comment: So if I have a min heap in this level order:                            level 0: 10
   level 1: 20, 25
   level 2: 60, 30, 58, 70
   level 3: 99, 70, 82, 50, 90, 85                                      then the values in the array are filled from left to right starting from level 0 right? 10, 20, 25, 60, ...?

Answer (score 2):

As Dan said the mapping is the same whatever the size of the array. If it helps, here is the binary heap tree for the example you provided, with the second 70 (in level 3) changed to 71. [image: Binary heap tree]

You can get the binary heap array by traversing the tree top-down, left-to-right. Below is the resulting array with the indices shown below, so you can easily apply the mapping to an index and see what value occurs there and cross check with the tree rendition.

```
array  :  10 | 20 | 25 | 60 |  30 | 58 | 71 | 99 | 70 |  82 | 50 | 90 | 85
indices:   0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |   9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

I hope this clears up your doubts.